# How to get arc4Sin() output into label/NSString

Tags: objective-c, random, nsstring, casting, arc4random

I'm trying to take the output of arc4sin and put it into a label.

(EDIT: You can ignore this and just post sample code, if this is too irrelevant.)

I've tried:

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *number =  [[NSString alloc] stringWithFormat: @"%@", arc4random() % 9];
    label.text = number;
}
```

I've created an IBOutlet for "label" and connected it. What's wrong here?

Comment: Either this isn't actual code you've tried or you're ignoring some obvious build errors, because `[[NSString alloc] stringWithFormat:` is nonsense without even reading on. It should either be `[NSString stringWithFormat:` or `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:` (and if it's the latter, it needs to be released afterward).

Comment: ah ok. I am a noob who is quite asleep right now. hehe. "nonsense without reading on".  True that.

Comment: @Carl - youe second code suggestion causes an error too. The first one works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cocoa format strings, `%@` denotes an Objective-C **object**, which ints, floats, longs, and shorts all aren't. They are just C datatypes, and use their own formats, the exact same as in `printf()`.

According to the manpage, arc4random() is defined as `u_int32_t arc4random(void);`, thus, you should use the `%u` format specifier (unsigned integer).

Edit: Thanks to Till for pointing this out: you want `-initWithFormat:` if you are calling `-alloc`, `-stringWithFormat:` is a class method of NSString.

Comment: Nope, still crashes... There's probably something else wrong with my code. Any ideas?

Comment: A UIAlertView works, something is up with my label or outlet... Thanks!

Comment: You are sending 'stringWithFormat:' to an allocated object although it's a class method.